# When trying to add items to a JavaFX TableView through an ObservableList, the TableView items won't show

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm making a grocery list app, and it has the feature to add items to the list(a tableview) along with the # of items and price. THe thing is, it works(because the tableview doesnt say "No content in table") But the table is blank. Any suggestions? 
Code:

```
package listproject;



public class Main extends Application{

public Node getNodeByRowColumnIndex(final int row,final int column,GridPane gridPane) {
    Node result = null;
    ObservableList<Node> childrens = gridPane.getChildren();
    for(Node node : childrens) {
        if(gridPane.getRowIndex(node) == row && gridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == column) {
            result = node;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

ObservableList<Product> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(

        );

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Grocery List");
    primaryStage.setWidth(450);
    primaryStage.setHeight(800);
    //menu buttons
    Button addLinkMain = new Button("Add an Item");
    Button addLinkTitle = new Button("Add an Item");
    Button mainLinkAdd = new Button("Back");
    Button mainLinkTitle = new Button("Back");
    Button addItem = new Button("Add");
    Button setTitleMenu = new Button("Set Title");
    Button setTitleAdd = new Button("Set Title");
    Button clear = new Button("Clear");

    //items for the item addition screen
    TextField title = new TextField("Name");
    TextField quantity = new TextField("#");
    TextField price = new TextField("$");
    HBox addBox = new HBox();
    BorderPane addBorder = new BorderPane();
    HBox addMenu = new HBox();
    //mainScene items
    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

    HBox mainscenemenu=new HBox();


    TableView<Product> tableview = new TableView<Product>();

    //tableview items
    TableColumn itemTitle=new TableColumn("Product");
    TableColumn itemQuantity=new TableColumn("Quantity");
    TableColumn itemPrice=new TableColumn("Price");

    //settitle items
    TextField listTitle= new TextField("Rename the List");
    Button setTittle = new Button("Set List Title");
    BorderPane setTitlePane=new BorderPane();
    StackPane setTitleFieldContainer=new StackPane();
    HBox setTitleOwnMenu = new HBox();
    //Scene declaration
    Scene mainScene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
    Scene addScene = new Scene(addBorder);
    Scene setTitleScene = new Scene(setTitlePane);
    //Main Scene    
    pane.setCenter(tableview);
    pane.setBottom(mainscenemenu);
    tableview.getColumns().addAll(itemTitle,itemQuantity,itemPrice);
    mainscenemenu.getChildren().addAll(setTitleMenu,clear,addLinkMain);
    tableview.setItems(data);
    //Item Addition Scene
    addBox.getChildren().addAll(title,quantity,price);
    addMenu.getChildren().addAll(mainLinkAdd,addItem,setTitleAdd);
    addBorder.setCenter(addBox);
    addBorder.setBottom(addMenu);

    //Set Title Scene
    setTitleFieldContainer.getChildren().addAll(listTitle);
    setTitleOwnMenu.getChildren().addAll(addLinkTitle,setTittle,mainLinkTitle);
    setTitlePane.setCenter(setTitleFieldContainer);
    setTitlePane.setBottom(setTitleOwnMenu);
    //Menu Button Event Handlers
    addLinkMain.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            primaryStage.setScene(addScene);
        }
    });
    addLinkTitle.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            primaryStage.setScene(addScene);
        }
    });
    mainLinkAdd.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);          
        }
    });
    mainLinkTitle.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);          
        }
    });
    setTitleMenu.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            primaryStage.setScene(setTitleScene);          
        }
    });
    setTitleAdd.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            primaryStage.setScene(setTitleScene);          
        }
    });

    //Adding an Item to the List *unfinished
    addItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){


        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            data.add(new Product(title.getText(),quantity.getText(),price.getText()));

        }

    });

    //Changing the Title of The List

    setTittle.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            primaryStage.setTitle(listTitle.getText());
        }

    });

    //Clearing the List

    clear.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            tableview.getItems().clear();
        }

    });

    //Show the Stage
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set the `cellValueFactory`s for the table's columns. You need to do this to specify the part of the items that should be displayed in the column.

An example with anonymus classes as `cellValueFactory`s can be found here.

Using `PropertyValueFactory` could reduce the amount of code needed. More about this here.

A tutorial can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm